# Merge those 2 V-sync questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, question-merge-request

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/198184/61395) now has a bounty and [this older one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/23248/61395) got also a good answer on V-Sync.

I feel the newest one should have been closed as a duplicate of the oldest but the accepted answer on the newest is as good as, if not a bit better thanks to the screenshot, than the accepted of the oldest.

So, which should be merged into the other?

The newest question does provide more information than the oldest with links (strangely not of the oldest question... wonder why).

Answer (score 1):

I am of the opinion the older question should be closed as a duplicate of the newer one.  No merge necessary.

**But wait!  Why are we closing a question as a dupe of a question that didn't exist when it was asked!**

As you've pointed out, the newer one is better.  If we had caught that it was a dupe *before* so much information was put there, we could've closed the newer one as a dupe of the older.  As it stands now, however, I am of the option that the newer one is more useful, and anyone who reads the older should read the newer, which would be facilitated by a "duplicate" link.

Comment: I would rather see them merged as both answers provide good information and them being at the same place would be better than having to click a link. V-Sync is a touchy subject that I think merging all the good information together would be better in the long run.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Merging is a touchy issue because you have to decide *which question to keep* when both have their merits.  Closing one as a dupe effectively merges the *information* (with a link) while side-stepping the problems brought up by an actual question merge.

Comment: I'm biased as I'm the author of the older question, but I don't think the newer one is better. It mostly just contains a large passage about where the answer wasn't found, which is just unnecessary in my opinion. The answer on the new question is better, though.

Comment: @MadScientist That's partly why I feel it is a little better as it clearly shows that the asker made a good effort to research (let's no argue about him not finding your question... ok fine, he didn,t do a great research after all).